# Aligning a vertical <img> to a centrally positioned <table> in CSS

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align an **image** tag `class="right-slider"` to the **table** tag same as the picture attached below **index.html** and have them display 100% on screen no matter which screen size.

anyone can help me? 
Thanks

**[index.html screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgf8G.png)**

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: segoe ui light;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


.resources {
  width: 1483px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #e0832c;
  color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.resources:hover {
  width: 1498px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: medium;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

td {
  border: none;
  height: 120px;
  width: 210px;
  background-color: #ccc3c3;
  color: #f2eaea;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

td:hover {
  width: 210px;
  height: 123px;
  background-color: #a09a9a;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 85px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 85px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 85px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

th {
  color: white;
  background-color: grey ;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 15px;
}



a {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}



.right-slider {
  float: right;
  margin: 33 98 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body><!--HTML Code-->
    <div>
      <a href=""><img class="right-slider" src="rightslider.png" height="680px"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="resources">Resource Assignment</div>
    <table>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
      <th>Sunday</th>
      <tr>    <!--1st week-->
        <td>01</td>
        <td>02</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>07</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>    <!--2nd week-->
        <td>08</td>
        <td>09</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>    <!--3rd week-->
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>    <!--4th week-->
        <td>22</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>28</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>    <!--5th week-->
        <td>29</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>31</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>02</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>04</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you made a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) with your html.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your quick reply, I have added my HTML and CSS code snippets is that what you meant? or I have alternatively added the image screenshot of what I want to achieve... I have updated the image "index.html"

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. You can read about it in the [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in my comment.

Comment: Oh I read it now thru your link, I will try to do that. Thanks!

Comment: I edit with a stacksnippet, not neccesary now @alimarwan

Comment: Thanks Marcos!! I saw that lol! if you notice the missing image when you run the snippet, and compare it with the screenshot i attached. that's the slider I want to align it to the table and whenever the website opens in different screen sizes it remains aligned and fullscreen without breaking up!

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dipali_vasani/4mn2ba8e/)

update following css :

```
table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width:96%;
}
.right-slider {
  float: right;
  margin: 33 98 0 0;
  position: relative;
  width:4%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dipali, I tried the code above, the .right-slider goes up the screen and take all the white space in the middle causing the table to go directly underneath :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use vh (viewport height) :

```
.right-slider {
float: right;
margin-top: 50vh;
}
```

Comment: Thank you samfred, the img and table break out when scaling down the browser... doesn't work either!

Comment: Would it be possible to wrap img and table tags inside a div and only position the div via CSS ? I tried to do so but I lack of some CSS magic

Comment: Yes, you can wrap img and table in another div, and set for example : min-width: 600px;

Comment: Tried, but still having the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Flexbox if you don't need to support old browsers :

```
#wrapper{
display: flex;
}
.right-slider {
  margin:auto;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1foapze/)

Comment: Hi Sam, I will try to use the above suggested and will let you know :) thanks!!